# Weaker version of the $A.M.\;-\;G.M.$ inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It is a well known fact that, for $\mathbf{x} \in R^k$ with $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_k) \geq 0$, $A(\mathbf{x})=G(\mathbf{x})$ iff $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$, where $A(\mathbf{x})$ and $G(\mathbf{x})$ are the Arithmetic Mean and Geometric Mean of $x_1,...,x_k$ respectively. (Attainment of equality in AM-GM inequality).

My question is, does, for any $\epsilon>0$,  $|A(\mathbf{x})-G(\mathbf{x})| <\epsilon \implies \sum_{i,j}|x_i-x_j|<c $ $ \epsilon$ for some constant $c$, and vice versa.

To state in words: From the A.M-G.M. inequality condition, it is known that A.M. and G.M. are **equal** iff the individual terms are **equal**. Now, does this hold, that A.M. and G.M. are **close enough**,  implies the individual terms are **close enough** to each other? and vice versa.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122411/almost-converses-to-the-am-gm-inequality